# google spreadsheet display values from script in multiple cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying out google apps script for the first time. I set up this script with an api key in a google spreadsheet and added it to the url variable in the script. The script runs without errors, but I can't figure out how to display specific variables in individual cells. I've looked at the documentation, but haven't come across similar examples yet.

If I have ISBN's in column A, what would I put in column B to display the title?

```
function getBookDetails(isbn) {

// Query the book database by ISBN code.
isbn = isbn || "9781451648546"; // Steve Jobs book 

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?key=myAPI&q=isbn:" + isbn;

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var results = JSON.parse(response);

if (results.totalItems) {

// There'll be only 1 book per ISBN
var book = results.items[0];

var title = (book["volumeInfo"]["title"]);
var subtitle = (book["volumeInfo"]["subtitle"]);
var authors = (book["volumeInfo"]["authors"]);
var printType = (book["volumeInfo"]["printType"]);
var pageCount = (book["volumeInfo"]["pageCount"]);
var publisher = (book["volumeInfo"]["publisher"]);
var publishedDate = (book["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"]);
var webReaderLink = (book["accessInfo"]["webReaderLink"]);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
var resultRow = [[isbn,title,subtitle,authors,printType,pageCount,publisher,publishedDate,webReaderLink]];
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,resultRow.length,resultRow[0].length).setValues(resultRow);
```

Comment: Awesome Serge, that works! There was one little typo in the code though towards the end. I changed steValues to setValues.

Comment: One issue though, it displays the example isbn number in the script, but when I have a ISBN number in A1 and put =getBookDetails(A1) in cell A2, I get an error: You do not have permission to call setValues (line 32).

Comment: you can't change the content of another cell from a custom function in a cell (that's probably what you are trying to do...), could you show the exact code you use

Comment: So I noticed :) I ended up simply using `return resultRow;` (see code in answer below). The script I have so far is not really usable though, since it makes an api call for every isbn. I already reached my api call limit..I'd have to come up with another approach to load the list with fewer api calls, or preferably only make an api call for new entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getBookDetails(isbn) {

// Query the book database by ISBN code.

if (isbn !== "") { 

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?key=AIzaSyAsTRXP0Eqy0Q4mQ1A00xQWYVzcgHyBKiM&q=isbn:" + isbn;

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var results = JSON.parse(response);

if (results.totalItems) {

// There'll be only 1 book per ISBN
var book = results.items[0];

var title = (book["volumeInfo"]["title"]);
var subtitle = (book["volumeInfo"]["subtitle"]);
var authors = (book["volumeInfo"]["authors"]);
var printType = (book["volumeInfo"]["printType"]);
var pageCount = (book["volumeInfo"]["pageCount"]);
var publisher = (book["volumeInfo"]["publisher"]);
var publishedDate = (book["volumeInfo"]["publishedDate"]);
var webReaderLink = (book["accessInfo"]["webReaderLink"]);

// For debugging
Logger.log(book);

}
var resultRow = [[title,authors]];


return resultRow;

// var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,resultRow.length,resultRow[0].length).setValues(resultRow);  
 }
}
```